# Add images in select dropdown box

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-select

I am trying to add small images as the options in a drop down box in a form, rather than text. 
It works in firefox (but nobody uses firefox anymore right?!) so need a way to do this for chrome primarily. I keep coming across this ddslick thing but I cannot download it from their site so want an alternate method.
Any help is appreciated!

HTML:

```css
select#severity option[value="Minor"] {
  background: url(../assets/constants/minor.png);
}
select#severity option[value="Moderate"] {
  background: url(../assets/constants/moderate.png);
}
select#severity option[value="Major"] {
  background: url(../assets/constants/major.png);
}
```

```html
<div class="variables">
  <select name="severity" id="severity" class="icon-menu">
    <option value="Severity" selected disabled>Please Select</option>
    <option value="Minor">Minor</option>
    <option value="Moderate">Moderate</option>
    <option value="Major">Major</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please add html

Comment: where is your code? Have you try anythings please post here.

Comment: Please, show your minimal code that works in Firefox but doesn't in Chrome.

Comment: OK added, for the CSS I hadn't bothered adding any formatting as I could see images weren't appearing in chrome, only in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
<select name="webmenu" id="webmenu">
    <option value="calendar" data-image="icons/icon_calendar.gif">Calendar</option>
    <option value="shopping_cart" data-image="icons/icon_cart.gif">Shopping Cart</option>
    <option value="cd" data-image="icons/icon_cd.gif">CD</option>
    <option value="email"  selected="selected" title="icons/icon_email.gif">Email</option>
    <option value="faq" data-image="icons/icon_faq.gif">FAQ</option>
    <option value="games" data-image="icons/icon_games.gif">Games</option>
  </select>
```

Credit from http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI has a Selectmenu that you can use for this: https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#custom_render